# How to create multiple columns when map the column data in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create three additional columns from one column , I have datetime and categorial data , I want to show the number of categories contain each row for example

**I have the date, categories and count. This is the dataframe**

[image]

I want to show the output with mapping like this

[image]

Where I have map the categories in two columns , such as 1 is fair, 2 is good and 3 is Great.
After mapping I want to add the count value into the additional map categories created
Now when I am trying to map I get

**'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'**

```
columns = ['Fair', 'Good', 'Great']
categories = {1: 'Fair', 2: 'Good', 3: 'Great'}
SampleResult=SampleResult['Categories'].applymap(categories.get)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of pandas [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

Considering your original dataframe containing  columns `CreatedDate`, `Categories` and `count`

```
categories = {1: 'Fair', 2: 'Good', 3: 'Great'}
out_dataframe = SampleResult.pivot(columns="Categories", values=["count"], index="CreatedDate").rename(columns=categories)
```

This will give you required output.